# How to identify the volume button is pressed or not from service?

Tags: android

From android app How to identify the volume button is pressed from service.

Getting from the volume level from a service from settings provider is right way to get it ?

Is their any right API exposed by android to identify ?

Answer (score -1):

This type of question was already made, but the answer is quick and I have no problem to give it here:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
        // Code
    }
    else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        // Code
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: From service it doesn,t work ...Any way ?